# Use lambda in pandas.replace does not return value, but a lambda function

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do a replace in pandas using Regex, and then modifying the Regex result itself. For example, I want to look for dates in any columns in the dataframe that contain a gap to remove it, e.g. `02/08/ 2023` would be `02/08/2023` (They always have a gap after the second /). In principle, I don't know the name of the columns which contain these dates, and they are always strings.

The code I am using to replace is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

technologies = {
    'Courses':["Spark","PySpark","Hadoop",pd.NaT],
    'Fee' :[20000,25000,26000,22000],
    'Duration':['30day','40days',np.nan, None],
    'Discount':[1000,2300,1500,1200],
    'Date':["23/3/ 2022","99/5/ 34","7/7/ 2122","6/12/ 2024"],
               }
indexes=['r1','r2','r3','r4']
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies,index=indexes)
print(df.replace(r'(\d+/\d+/ \d+)', lambda x: x.group(1).replace(" ", ""), regex=True))
#        Courses    Fee Duration  Discount                                   Date
#r1    Spark  20000    30day      1000  <function <lambda> at 0x148adb9c71f0>
#r2  PySpark  25000   40days      2300  <function <lambda> at 0x148adb9c71f0>
#r3   Hadoop  26000      NaN      1500  <function <lambda> at 0x148adb9c71f0>
#r4      NaT  22000     None      1200  <function <lambda> at 0x148adb9c71f0>
```

But this code shows me a lambda function when printing the dataframe. However, if I use a re.sub:

```
import re

txt = "That will be 59/3/ 3432 dollars"

#Find all digit characters:

x = re.sub(r"(\d+/\d+/ \d+)", lambda x: x.group(1).replace(" ", ""), txt)
print(x)
# That will be 59/3/3432 dollars
```

This code shows the correct answer. Why pandas shows me lambda function instead of the real value? How can I fix it?

Comment: TIL the second arg in `re.sub` can be a function

Comment: Take a look at `help(pandas.Dataframe.replace)`. It clearly shows that second arg's signature is `value : scalar, dict, list, str, regex, default None`, i.e. it doesn't accept a callable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to captured groups as shown below:

```
print(df.replace(r'(\d+/\d+/) (\d+)', r'\1\2', regex=True))
```

---

```
    Courses    Fee Duration  Discount       Date
r1    Spark  20000    30day      1000  23/3/2022
r2  PySpark  25000   40days      2300    99/5/34
r3   Hadoop  26000      NaN      1500   7/7/2122
r4      NaT  22000     None      1200  6/12/2024
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the spaces in the group, as desired in the OP.

Comment: @Barmar, read the question, the OP has clearly written "They always have a gap after the second /"

Answer (score 1):

`Pandas.Dataframe.replace()` doesn't accept a function as the replacement value, so it simply converts it to a string.

To use a function replacement like in `re.sub()` you have to use [`Pandas.Series.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace)

```
df.Date = df.Date.str.replace(r'(\d+/\d+/ \d+)', lambda x: x.group(1).replace(" ", ""), regex=True)
print(df)
```

prints

```
    Courses    Fee Duration  Discount       Date
r1    Spark  20000    30day      1000  23/3/2022
r2  PySpark  25000   40days      2300    99/5/34
r3   Hadoop  26000      NaN      1500   7/7/2122
r4      NaT  22000     None      1200  6/12/2024
```

Comment: Although useful, in principle I don't know the names of columns and must be for all columns, which @RomanPerekhrest's answer does.